# Extracting pipe delimted field into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a tbl with a field with values that are pipe delimited, and I need them extracted as rows.

Sample data

```
select distinct [PROV_KEY], 
[NTWK_CDS]
FROM [SPOCK].[US\AC39169].[WellPointExtract_ERR]
where [PROV_KEY] = '447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25'
--results
PROV_KEY    NTWK_CDS
447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25    |GA_HMO|GA_OPN|GA_PPO|GA_BD|GA_MCPPO|GA_HDPPO|
```

And I would like:

```
PROV_KEY                                          NTWK_CDS
447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25                  GA_HMO
447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25                  GA_OPN
447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25                  GA_PPO
```

I tried the following but I'm only getting the first set of values:

```
select distinct [PROV_KEY], 
substring([NTWK_CDS], 1, 
CHARINDEX('|',[NTWK_CDS], CHARINDEX('|',[NTWK_CDS])+1)) 
FROM [SPOCK].[US\AC39169].[WellPointExtract_ERR]
where [PROV_KEY] = '447358B0A8E1C0F1B7AEB1ED07EC2F25'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard string splitting problem and there are many solutions out there. However most still feel like a workaround, as SQL Server does not have a split function build in.

You can start your research here: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Answer (score 0):

The crucial operation you need to perform is a split. There are lots of solutions to this problem (see [here](http://florianreischl.blogspot.com/2009/09/high-performance-string-split-functions.html) for some), and people favor different ones depending on both situation and personal preference. Once you've done the split, though, you can JOIN or APPLY against the results to get the desired output.

I personally prefer using a SQLCLR function for this purpose since the performance is generally much better; but the number of options out there is staggering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use splitting function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(@List nvarchar (1000), @Delimiter nvarchar(1 ))
RETURNS @returns TABLE(val nvarchar(100), [level] int, PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([level]))
AS
BEGIN
;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(@List, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter , @List)) AS val ,
         CAST(STUFF(@List + @Delimiter, 1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List),'') AS nvarchar (1000)) AS stval,
         1 AS [level]
  UNION ALL
  SELECT SUBSTRING(stval, 0, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, stval)),
         CAST(STUFF(stval, 1 , CHARINDEX(@Delimiter ,stval), '') AS nvarchar(1000)),
         [level] + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE stval != ''
  )
  INSERT @returns
  SELECT REPLACE(val ,' ' ,'') AS val, [level]
  FROM cte
  RETURN
END
```

Hence, your SELECT statement will be

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.test82 t CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_CTE(t.NTWK_CDS, '|') o
WHERE o.val != ''
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/393b5/2)